# Attempt to read property "cat_name" on null || foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

There is a relationship between the two models. And I want to display category name instead of category_id in products.blade.php. I am getting errors.

> foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given.

```
@foreach ($product->category as $category)
    <td>{{$category->cat_name}}</td>
@endforeach.
```

> Attempt to read property "cat_name" on null.

```
<td>{{$product->category->cat_name}}</td>
```

**Products model**

```
class Products extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    // use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categories');
    }
}
```

**Categories model**

```
class Categories extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = ['cat_name','image'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Products');
    }
}
```

**ProductsController**

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Products::all();

        return view('product.products',compact('products'));
    }
```

**products.blade.php**

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
@foreach ($products as $product)
<?php $i++ ?>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$i}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->category->cat_name}}</td>
        {{-- @foreach ($product->category as $category)
        <td>{{$category->cat_name}}</td>
        @endforeach --}}
        <td>{{$product->description}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
        <td>wefre</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Product -> Category is a belongsTo relationship. It returns **a single record** or null.

```xml
<td>{{ $product->category?->cat_name }}</td>
```

or, if you're not using php8

```xml
<td>{{ optional($product->category)->cat_name }}</td>
```

---

You should also eager load the relationship or else you'll have a query for each `$product` in `$products` (N+1 queries). Some of laravel's newer versions throw an error when this occurs.

```php
$products = Product::with('category')->get();
```

---

Also, instead of `$i`, you can use the `$loop` variable exposed by the `@foreach` directive.

```xml
@foreach ($products as $product)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->category->cat_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
    <td>wefre</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```